# PHP script won't connect but FileZilla works

Tags: php, ftp, filezilla

I have a very weird problem that I cannot seem to figure out. I have purchased a GoDaddy web server that enables me to connect remotely, via FTP. Now when I use `FileZilla` to connect, it allows me to and I can roam my files at my leisure. But I have written a `PHP` script to connect  to the server, with the same information and it does not allow me too. It gives me an error such as `Cannot connect to FTP Server` (has seen in my script). I have tried to remove the port and timeout, and still nothing. I have figured out, however, that it is the initial connection that is failing (as commented). I am lost at why it is not allowing me which FileZilla clearly works.

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "IP";
//It does not get pass here, the ERROR happens right here
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server, "21","90") or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, "USER", "PASS");

$file = "test.txt";

// upload file 
if (ftp_put($ftp_conn, "serverfile.txt", $file, FTP_ASCII))
{
echo "Successfully uploaded $file.";
}
else
{
echo "Error uploading $file.";
}

// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

This is what is echoed to me with a TryCatch

```
Warning: ftp_login() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/85/9844385/html/Test/Upload/upload.php on line 7

Warning: ftp_put() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/85/9844385/html/Test/Upload/upload.php on line 12
Error uploading test.txt.
Warning: ftp_close() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/content/85/9844385/html/Test/Upload/upload.php on line 22
```

Comment: It sounds like your FTP server has some sort of a firewall stopping your PHP server from talking to it.  Is it possible to get the error string to print out so you can see what the problem is?

Comment: Are you able to access a different FTP server with your script or is it just GoDaddy's ftp that you cannot connect to?

Comment: Is php running under a user that has ftp rights? try `psasthru('groups')` and check - Oh, and please don't use `or die`

Comment: @durbnpoisn that is my error.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem How would I use that? It seems like it is my `$ftp_conn` that is problem, it does not get past there. Also, what is wrong with `or die` :(

Comment: @SomeRandomUser: [RTM](http://www.php.net/passthru). You see what user is running your code, see if it has ftp-privileges. What is wrong with `or die`: apart from a horrid syntax, a low-precedence operator: code that establishes a connection is, in well-structured programs abstracted, and doesn't control the flow of the rest of the app. `die` terminates the entire run, but code that establishes an ftp connection isn't (and shouldn't) be aware of any other types of resources that are in use. It should throw an exception and let the code that _does_ know of other resources decide: fatal or not

Comment: I m also having same issue.